# When fetching a user from the db, how should I check for null?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I attempt to fetch a record from the db like:

```
@user = User.find_by_user_name("blah")
```

How do I check if the value was null? i.e. the record was found?

And should I use `and` or `&&` as they seem to be different?

```
if @user and @user.age > 0
  ....
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if @user
  # not nil
else
  # nil
end
```

should be suffice to check if the value was not nil.

And the difference between && and 'and' is that && has a higher precedence over 'and'. See [here](http://www.themomorohoax.com/2008/12/08/and-vs-amperand-in-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

This will raise an exception if the value is null:

```
@user = User.find_by_user_name!("blah")
```

Answer (score 0):

If there's no record, @user will be nil, so an if check will work.

The difference between && and and is precedence. && has higher precedence.

Answer (score 0):

@user will be nil if it hasn't been found, as suggested. You can check for nil explicitly like so, of course:

```
@user.nil?
@user === nil
```

nil will falsify an if statement, like false. See [NilClass](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/NilClass.html) and [FalseClass](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/FalseClass.html) for differences.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, the finder will return `nil` if the record was not found, thus you have a few options, including the one you mentioned in your question and the other answers here.

Since `@user = User.find_by_user_name("blah")` evaluates to `nil` if the user isn't found, I personally prefer the following Ruby idiom:

```
if @user = User.find_by_user_name("blah")
  # do stuff with @user
else
  # not found
end
```